# Need input in analyzing GC Report

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm trying to figure out a reson for slow response of an application. I need some input in regards to GC log. I analyzed the log and noticed that in duration of around 2 hours, Minor GC ran 3363 times and reclaimed around 60 gb. GC interval average time is around 2 seconds and Concurrent mode failed once.

Are these things normal in any enterprise application? Full GC count is 8 with average time 28ms. What else I should be checking in GC log?

JVM paramters used:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=4
```

If it helps following is the URL of the analysis report:

http://gceasy.io/my-gc-report.jsp?p=c2hhcmVkLzIwMTYvMDkvMS8tLXRlc3QubG9nLS0xMS00NS0xNw==

Comment: It depends what exactly you are looking for, from the GC graph it looks everything alright to me...

Comment: Which version of the JDK you use ? Why you inspect the GC, do you encounter issue in production ?

Comment: Java version "1.6.0_45". Yes, it is happening in production and as a workaround we restart application after every 2 hours.

Comment: the title says "analyzing GC log", but you have not posted a log.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no trouble with GC so maybe you can use VisualVM + VisualGC plugin to have more details about thread and see in which method time is spend.

Increase -Xmx and see if it slow down later.